# Is there a normed space that it has a element (except 0) that every functional of the dual of the normed space mapping it to 0?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a normed vector space, $X'$ is its dual space. My question is is there a $X$ satisfied the following condition.

There is a element $x$ in $X$ which is not $0$ and it satisfied that every functional of the dual space $X'$ mapping $x$ to $0$.

The reason that I ask this question is because that I read the mapping $J$ whose value $Jx$ at $x\in X$ is given by $Jx(x')=x'(x) \quad x'\in X'$ is a injection in the book. So why $J$ is a injection?

Comment: like the `annihilator` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \neq 0$, then you can show via the Hahn-Banach Theorem that there is a linear functional $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x) = \left|\left|x\right|\right|$.  As for your second question, you're concerned with the map:
$$J: X \to X'' \ , \ x \mapsto J(x)$$
where we have that:
$$\forall x \in X: \forall f \in X': J(x)(f) := f(x)$$
This can be shown to be injective by proving that it is an isometry (this is usually how it is done when this inclusion is first introduced) but a direct argument is also possible. Indeed, let $J(x) = 0$. That means that for every $f \in X'$, we have that $J(x)(f) = f(x) = 0$. But this implies that $x = 0$ by the statement I mentioned above (the one involving the Hahn-Banach Theorem).